# How to properly install virtualenvwrapper to my Mac?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm trying to follow the Mozilla Django guide:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/development_environment

Following the steps in the guide, I've successfully installed Python3.7.3 and pip3. When I enter `python3 -V` and `pip3 list` I get the expected responses.

### Step 1

The next step is to install **virtualenvwrapper**. I did this with the recommended command:

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenvwrapper
```

However when I hit enter I got the following warnings:

```
The directory '/Users/myusername/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/myusername/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting virtualenvwrapper
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c1/6b/2f05d73b2d2f2410b48b90d3783a0034c26afa534a4a95ad5f1178d61191/virtualenvwrapper-4.8.4.tar.gz (334kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 337kB 9.9MB/s 
Collecting virtualenv (from virtualenvwrapper)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ca/ee/8375c01412abe6ff462ec80970e6bb1c4308724d4366d7519627c98691ab/virtualenv-16.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 2.0MB 14.1MB/s 
Collecting virtualenv-clone (from virtualenvwrapper)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ba/f8/50c2b7dbc99e05fce5e5b9d9a31f37c988c99acd4e8dedd720b7b8d4011d/virtualenv_clone-0.5.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting stevedore (from virtualenvwrapper)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c6/dc/6ee92bccfe3c0448786b30b693e6060d62ec8c4a3ec9a287bac1c1a8d8c9/stevedore-1.30.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (42kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 28.3MB/s 
Collecting pbr!=2.1.0,>=2.0.0 (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e0/27/a913b227c9053472ea7dda33e409a1e748e50cdd208a955f3d6a20e9a875/pbr-5.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (108kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 27.2MB/s 
Collecting six>=1.10.0 (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: virtualenv, virtualenv-clone, pbr, six, stevedore, virtualenvwrapper
  Running setup.py install for virtualenvwrapper ... done
Successfully installed pbr-5.3.0 six-1.12.0 stevedore-1.30.1 virtualenv-16.6.0 virtualenv-clone-0.5.3 virtualenvwrapper-4.8.4
```

### Step 2

The next step is to edit the file **virtualenvwrapper.sh**. I can find this in the directory `Macintosh HD/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`.

However, when I try to edit the file **virtualenvwrapper.sh** I get a warning from Xcode saying **virtualenvwrapper.sh is currently locked because you are not the owner of the file and do not have write permission.**

### Solutions

Doing some googling it seems I've got two options:

1. Install using the `sudo -H` command and use -H forever more. If so, do I need to uninstall my first installation of virtualenvwrapper + python3 + pip3?
2. Somehow change the permissions on my machine so I can edit these files. I am the only user of this Mac, so it wouldn't be an issue.

What is the recommended solution? 
Thanks in advance for your help.